# Unable to install third party module from http://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixa/

Tags: python

I'm learning to code from automatetheboringstuff.com

I am using a macOS Catalin trying to install a third party module mentioned on their website -- http://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixa/

Any ideas on the following error message can be fixed?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-ttej6vag/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/
    Complete output (176 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py", line 759, in <module>
        setup(name=NAME,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py", line 606, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py", line 804, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-s97edanm/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-ttej6vag/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try upgrading your Pip and Wheel versions first: `pip install -U pip wheel` .

Comment: You need to be more specific and provide what you did, what you typed on the terminal

Comment: I tried upgrading Pip and Wheel versions. I see the same error.

Comment: Originally,  I had typed in  pip3 install automateboringstuff1stedition in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, for whichever reason, there is no precompiled binary wheel of Pillow 7.1.1 for macOS, and your Pip is falling back to trying to compile things and failing to do so since you lack dependencies.

7.1.0 has a wheel, though, so try installing it:

```
pip install Pillow==7.1.0
```

Comment: Try to force or prefer binary installation? `pip install --prefer-binary Pillow` or `pip install --only-binary=:all: Pillow`